# Bitbucket external hook, how do I reconstruct the folder structure of the git repo?

Tags: python, git, bitbucket-server

I have written a python check which looks in a folder for (salt state) sls files, and checks for duplicates as they cause a weird error if you don't catch them. The script works fine if I run it in my local git repo, but I want to run it as an external hook on the server so I can enforce the rule on anyone doing the commit (rather than just having them in the .git/hooks folder and asking everyone else to use them and hoping they do). Using this [plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.ngs.stash.externalhooks.external-hooks/server/overview) you can set the hook up to run on the server, but when I ran my check on the server it doesn't work because the folder structure isn't like the branch I have locally, it's a git server so we have:

`['packed-refs', 'description', 'stash-refs', 'refs', 'branches', 'config', 'FETCH_HEAD', 'HEAD', 'objects', 'info', 'hooks', '.mailmap.new', 'logs']`

I asked a colleague and he mentioned he had written a script in another language (perl or ruby) which takes the content of the folder on the server and uses it to build the files in a branch to run the tests on.

I'm trying to find out how to do this in python, or if there is a better way to go about this I haven't considered yet.

I searched around but I'm finding it hard to describe that process in a search!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, it took me a few days and I had to copy the functionality of the ruby script my colleague had written to do it. the script ran to over 200 lines, so I won't put it on here, but to summerise what I needed to do:

- Take the stdin passed to the script
- Split that by spaces and you have a to and from reference and the branch name for each branch that the user is pushing (who knew you could push multiple branches at once?)
- For each of those, check to see if it's a new branch or a deleted branch as they're special cases
- Otherwise get the refs of each branch with `git show-ref --heads`
- Get the refs of previous commits with `git log --format="%H" [to_ref]`
- check through the refs of previous commits with the refs of each branch to find the branch the commit started on
- Get a list of files that have changed with `git diff --name-only [from_ref] [to_ref]`
- Get the content of the file with `git show [to_ref]:[file_name]`

Once I had that it allowed me to check through the full contents of each file that had been changed on the current commit.

Answer (score -1):

The git repository on the server is a [bare repo](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/). It has no working directory (what you call "branch", it seems), and no files are checked out.

The reason you see a different directory structure is because in bare repos, the metadata files that usually live in the `.git` subdirectory just live in the main repo directory. Compare the structure above with the contents of your local `repository/.git` directory and you'll see.

It seems you're using Bitbucket Server (just based on the tags on your question), so you are unable to change this there. The hooks you are able to run on Bitbucket can only do things based on the git metadata, not the actual contents of the repo.

You need to set up a build server somewhere that automatically tests the code in your repo, and then have hooks on Bitbucket that push to this build server and report on the results of the tests.

You can use something like [Docker Hub](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/06/docker-automated-builds-bitbucket/) or something else that's integrated with Bitbucket for easy setup, or perhaps even Atlassian's own continuous integration tool, [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery).

Comment: "The hooks you are able to run on Bitbucket can only do things based on the git metadata, not the actual contents of the repo." You can, I just finished writing the script to do it

Comment: @Rumbles I see your answer now – yes, the git metadata in a bare repo contains the state of the repo, but no working directory. I'm unsure how you from that managed to "to build the files in a branch to run the tests on" on Bitbucket using your script, however. But I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: Check my answer, I explain the process there, it's a bit difficult to follow, but someone smarter than me figured it out, and it seems to work. Basically, you can run git commands in the directory, and with git show you can retrieve a file from the bare repo, assuming you know the reference and the filename

Comment: Yes, I know and understand that part, but in your original question you asked how to build. That's why I mentioned build servers and CI. But nevermind, great that you solved your problem.

Comment: Build has nothing to do with bamboo in this context :)